# How to open generated pdf using jspdf in new window

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am using **jspdf** to generate a pdf file. Every thing is working fine. But how to open generated 
pdf in new tab or new window.

I am using

```
doc.output('datauri');
```

Which is opening the pdf in same tab.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Search in jspdf.js this:

   ```
   if(type == 'datauri') {
       document.location.href ='data:application/pdf;base64,' + Base64.encode(buffer);
   }
   ```
2. Add :

   ```
   if(type == 'datauriNew') {   
       window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,' + Base64.encode(buffer));
   }
   ```
3. call this option 'datauriNew' Saludos ;)

Comment: does not work in iOS 8. i found a soloution from @atroy here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21629499/2978727

Comment: Use 'dataurlnewwindow' with the newest version.

Comment: @Majestic12 This opens a blank page with the uri string in the address bar for me... I have to hit enter.

Answer (score 132):

Based on the source you can use the 'dataurlnewwindow' parameter for output():

```
doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
```

Source in github:
https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.js#L914

All possible cases:

```
doc.output('save', 'filename.pdf'); //Try to save PDF as a file (not works on ie before 10, and some mobile devices)
doc.output('datauristring');        //returns the data uri string
doc.output('datauri');              //opens the data uri in current window
doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');     //opens the data uri in new window
```

Comment: When I use doc.output('save', 'filename.pdf'); I receive this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: saveAs is not defined jspdf.js:975, i'm using chrome Version 29.0.1547.66 m.

Comment: @YaBasha You also need FileSaver.js.

Comment: `doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');` returns a blank page. Is there anything that I need to do before calling it?

Comment: in Chrome 60, `doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');` creates a new tab, with the url, but you have to press enter to load the pdf.  Using the blob option from @ilter works better.

Comment: doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');  returns a Blank Page Do I need to call any other method before this 
@devgirl  (Have you got the solution for the same )

Comment: Did anyone found the solution of why there is blank pdf in new tab when we use `doc.output('dataurlnewwindow')` . @PascalBelloncle

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama been have using `doc.save(...)` instead.  Has been working great.

Answer (score 27):

This solution working for me

```
window.open(doc.output('bloburl'))
```

Comment: window.open(pdf.output('bloburl'), '_blank');  works for me in Chrome

Answer (score 20):

I have to use this to load the PDF directly. Using `doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');` produces an ugly iframe for me. Mac/Chrome.

```
  var string = doc.output('datauristring');
  var x = window.open();
  x.document.open();
  x.document.location=string;
```

Comment: No need to use iframe just use doc.output('dataurlnewwindow', {})

Comment: @TheBackBencher `doc.output('dataurlnewwindow', {})` is consistently crashing the browser (Firefox).

Comment: same as 'doc.output('dataurlnewwindow'); - crashing the browser (Firefox)

Comment: @FullDecent 4 years later, but now it opens a blank page.

Answer (score 15):

this code will help you to open generated pdf in new tab with required title

```
 let pdf = new jsPDF();
 pdf.setProperties({
          title: "Report"
      });
      pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');
```

Comment: works perfectly in 2022

Answer (score 12):

Or...
You can use Blob to achive this.

Like:

```
pdf.addHTML($('#content'), y, x, options, function () {
    var blob = pdf.output("blob");
    window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
});
```

That code let you create a Blob object inside the browser and show it in the new tab.

Comment: A bit old thread but how can I generate the pdf file outside the addHTML? It seems 'blob' is a local variable so alert(blob) shows 'undefined'. Any clue?

Comment: @Gene9y it's even older, but you can use localStorage or indexeddb to store the blob.

Answer (score 10):

using javascript you can send the generated pdf to a new window using the following code.

```
var string = doc.output('datauristring');

var iframe = "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='" + string + "'></iframe>"

var x = window.open();
x.document.open();
x.document.write(iframe);
x.document.close();
```

Comment: JsPdf also has functionality for this. You can call the following method. doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');

Comment: The download button doesn't seem to work with this method.

Answer (score 10):

This is how I handle it.

```
window.open(doc.output('bloburl'), '_blank');
```

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut do you have any kind of Ad or Popup Blocker turned on?

Comment: The ublock origin ad-blocker blocks the request on chrome, It needs to be disabled for the page

Answer (score 4):

Generally you can [download it, show, or get a blob string](https://github.com/rusovd/jspldf_simplest):

```
const pdfActions = {
    save: () => doc.save(filename),
    getBlob: () => {
      const blob = doc.output('datauristring');
      console.log(blob)
      return blob
    },
    show: () => doc.output('dataurlnewwindow')
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Javascript code**

```
// IE doesn't allow using a blob object directly as link href
// instead it is necessary to use msSaveOrOpenBlob
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
  window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(doc.output("blob"), "Name.pdf");
} else {

  // For other browsers:
  // Create a link pointing to the ObjectURL containing the blob.
  doc.autoPrint();
  window.open(
    URL.createObjectURL(doc.output("blob")),
    "_blank",
    "height=650,width=500,scrollbars=yes,location=yes"
  );

  // For Firefox it is necessary to delay revoking the ObjectURL
  setTimeout(() => {    
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(doc.output("bloburl"));
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: You must disable ad blocker for it to work properly

Answer (score 3):

**STEP 1** 
Turn off addblock

**STEP 2**
Add

```
window.open(doc.output('bloburl'), '_blank');
```

Or try

```
doc.output('dataurlnewwindow')
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me!!!

When you specify window features, it will open in a new window

Just like :

```
window.open(url,"_blank","top=100,left=200,width=1000,height=500");
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, it is important to remember that the output method has other values and it might be interesting to test all of them to choose the ideal one for your case.

https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/jsPDF.html#output

test one line at a time:

```
doc.output('arraybuffer');
doc.output('blob');
doc.output('bloburi');
doc.output('bloburl');
doc.output('datauristring');
doc.output('dataurlstring');
doc.output('datauri');
doc.output('dataurl');
doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
doc.output('pdfobjectnewwindow');
doc.output('pdfjsnewwindow');
```

Answer (score 1):

Step I: include the file and plugin

```
../jspdf.plugin.addimage.js
```

Step II: build PDF content
var doc = new jsPDF();

```
doc.setFontSize(12);
doc.text(35, 25, "Welcome to JsPDF");
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 386, 386);
```

Step III: display image in new window

```
doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
```

Stepv IV: save data

```
var output = doc.output();
return btoa( output);
```

Comment: The `doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");` opens but doesn't render the PDF; however you can save and print it!

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript code:** Add in end line

```
$("#pdf_preview").attr("src", pdf.output('datauristring'));
```

**HTML Code: Insert in body**

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
<H1>Testing</h1>
<iframe id="pdf_preview" type="application/pdf" src="" width="800" height="400"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

preview within same window inside iframe along with with other contents.

Answer (score -2):

```
generatePdf():   {
const doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text('Hello, this is your PDF content!', 10, 10);
const blob = doc.output('blob');
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```