# How to make jsPDF convert big text?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I'm using jsPDF to convert html to pdf. When a page has a lot of text I just got a blank pdf or a gray page with no contentsanf **data:** in url

I have no errors in console.

How can I make it print pdf correctly?

To convert to pdf I use this code:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
     var specialElementHandlers = {
         '#editor': function (element,renderer) {
             return true;
         }
     };
     $('#topdf').click(function () {

      var doc = new jsPDF();

      var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function(element, renderer){
            return true;
        }
      };

      doc.fromHTML($('.post-content p').get(0), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170, 
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
      });

       doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in length of URL limit 2000 chars (more here: [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)), so I suggest you to use `doc.output('save', 'filename.pdf')` but this have limitation (more: [How to open generated pdf using jspdf in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739816/how-to-open-generated-pdf-using-jspdf-in-new-window))

Comment: But it this case text becomes a little ugly. If I use regular print as pdf from a browser text looks better.