# Decode base 64 to pdf javaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, base64, jspdf

I am implementing the pdf generation via client side using jsPDF. I can download the pdf but when displaying on a second tab I have problems because it generates a very large base64 and the browser does not read. When the data is few the browser reads but it is necessary to press the enter key.
Can anyone help me?

I tried to see some answers here but I did not succeed

My js code

```
gerarRelatorio=function() {

        var colunas = [ {title: "ID", dataKey: "idDistrito"},
            {title: "Nome", dataKey: "nome"},
            {title: "Código Dne", dataKey: "codigoDne"}, ]

        var linhas = $scope.distritos;

        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');

        doc.autoTable(colunas,  linhas, {
            styles: {fillColor: [230, 230, 230],  fontSize: 9},
            columnStyles: {
                id: {fillColor: [230, 230, 230], fontSize: 20},
            },

            margin: {top: 60},

            addPageContent: function(data) {
                 if ( $scope.distritos[0].entidade.brasao) {
                      doc.addImage($scope.distritos[0].entidade.brasao, 'JPEG', data.settings.margin.left, 12, 35, 40);

                  }
                doc.setFontSize(11);
                doc.text("ESTADO DO " + $scope.distritos[0].uf.nome + " " + $scope.distritos[0].entidade.nome, 90, 36 );    
                doc.text("Total de  " + $scope.distritos.length + " registros ", 455, 50 );
            }
        });

        doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
```

i got this error :

[image]

Comment: See answers here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739816/how-to-open-generated-pdf-using-jspdf-in-new-window](Juan Capello) May help you

Comment: i have sow this answer but not solve in my case.. i dont know what i did wrong..