# How to preview pdf file before save/download using jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

In my Javascript code I am using the jsPdf library to generate the pdf file. The code works fine.But now I need the preview before downloading the file.

```
const mydoc= new jsPDF();
mydoc.text("Welcome");
doc.save("test.pdf");
```

This works fine,it only downloads the file,but I want to preview before save/download.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open generated pdf using jspdf in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739816/how-to-open-generated-pdf-using-jspdf-in-new-window)

Comment: Thanks alot Mr.Chris for helping.....your solution worked for me.